# A testing framework for Linux server configuration management

Tags: linux, configuration, puppet, testing, configuration-management

We are a medium sized shop that uses Puppet for Linux configuration management. Since we are a small shop, it's difficult to deploy and maintain DTAP environment.

We normally perform manual testing after configuration changes. I would like to automate that somehow; like you would see in software regression testing for e.g..

An e.g. use-case would be an OpenLDAP cluster. I would:

1. I would make a change on a test node in the Puppet test environment
2. Test services
3. If fail, go back to to step 1
4. Remove a node from the cluster
5. Make the configuration change
6. Test services
7. If fail, go back to step 5
8. Add node back to cluster
9. Test services
10. If fail, go back to step 4
11. Finally, deploy to other nodes

Ideally, I'd like to automate the testing so we could deploy changes with more confidence.

Can anyone recommend such a thing? Preferably something that hooks into Puppet but not necessarily a requirement. Some suggestions on best practice would also be appreciated.

Comment: Acceptance testing spanning multiple test nodes is what `beaker` is for, see https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker. It allows you to define test scenarios that are run on (groups of) throwaway virtual machines.

Comment: @FelixFrank, shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil well, for lack of personal experience, I can really add no further information at all. Since the question is quite specific, I feel that the link doesn't qualify as a full answer. Just a helpful pointer. Hope someone will speak up and elaborate. - But thanks for the encouragement :-)

Comment: @FelixFrank please submit as an answer. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @BelminFernandez OK fine ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designated tool that meets the described requirements is [Beaker](https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker). It will allow the creation of acceptance test scenarios like the one that was sketched in the question.